# Config reads value from another config

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to setup configs so it is easy to switch from dev to production with out constantly having to copy config settings from one place to another.

What I am trying to do is to setup a singe config that contains usernames, passwords and other access strings that I want to omit from source control for obvious reasons.
I could then reference those keys in other configs.

An example of what I am thinking

Content of a config that stores keys:

```
<keys>
    <add key="username" value="1forest1" />
    <add key="password" value="life-is-like-a-box-of-chocolates" />
    <add key="url" value="http://www.example.com" />
</keys>
```

Content of a config that requires keys:

```
<service name="SomeService">
    <settings>
        <setting key="Container" value="MyContainer" />
        <setting key="MaxBytes" value="12582912" />
        <setting key="Timeout" value="30000" />
        <setting key="Host" value=[url value from keys config] />
        <setting key="username" value=[username value from keys config] />
        <setting key="password" value=[password value from keys config] />
    </settings>
</service>
```

I am not to optimistic that this is possible due to reasons, but any patterns that might point towards a solution/workaround for this would greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just use web.config transforms

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration tools. Adding json files.

```
IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
   .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
   .AddJsonFile("Secrets/values.json")
   .Build();
```

Inject the Configuration then get the values:

```
var section = configuration.GetSection("Settings");
string connectionString = section["ConnectionString"]
```

json example:

```
{
  "Settings": {
    "ConnectionString": "Server=tcp.....",
    "SomeOtherValue": "SomeValue"
  },
  "MoreStuff": {
    "foo": "bar"
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Have an appsettings file:

Web.config:

```
<appSettings file="AppSettingsSecrets.config">
  <add key="Container" value="MyContainer" />
  <add key="MaxBytes" value="12582912" />
  <add key="Timeout" value="30000" />
  <add key="Host" value="" />
  <add key="username" value="" />
  <add key="password" value="" />
</appSettings>
```

AppSettingsSecrets.config :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<appSettings>
    <add key="Host" value="SecretHost" />
    <add key="username" value="MyUname" />
    <add key="password" value="S3cr3t" />
</appSettings>
```

2. Give the location/name of the second config file as one setting in first config file, and read it dynamically.

Comment: I like that, but sadly that only applies to appSettings.